# Small FSM like code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, design-patterns

In an html page I have 2 checkboxes that "complement" each other.
In a nutshell *only* the following states are valid (will explain this):

```
Checkbox1     Checkbox2     
    TRUE        FALSE    
    TRUE        TRUE
```

Also note that when checkbox2 is clicked to be set to true then I programmatically click checkbox1 to be checked.
Of course both can be FALSE but this is a state that I ignore.
What I mean so far is that I use these checkboxes to do a running sum over a table or rows. According to these states I add the amounts or subtract.
What I have done works but it seems error-prone and hard to extend. Basically I keep a few global variables which I set/reset according to the states of the checkbox and in one case to signify the previous state and the following state.
Is there a nice way to implement an FSM like code around this functionality I have?

Answer (score 0):

To do such things, I use a library called iFSM that I made to handle GUI problems like the one you describe...

You can see here how I implement your case with this library : http://www.intersel.fr/assets/gitdemos/iFSM/Example_Checkbox.html

The library is available on github here: https://github.com/intersel/iFSM